# Is it possible to send GZip'd HTTP POST request by using PAW

Tags: gzip, paw-app

Is it possible to send gzip'd HTTP POST requests in Paw?

I have accept-encoding, content-encoding set to gzip but it seems to be not enough to get it to work.

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Encoding: gzip
Accept: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip
X-Protocol-Version: 2
User-Agent: test-ua
Host: host123:8080
Connection: close
Content-Length: 120

[{"user-id":"123","p-id":"1"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that. It is not possible at the moment to send gzip'ed body automatically.
If you use "Content-Encoding: gzip" you must gzip the body and drop the file into Paw. Paw is sending the gzip'ed body without any issue. I am using Paw version 2.2.5.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to gzip the body yourself and then paste it in.  I could be wrong and if so would love this auto gzip feature!

Comment: Sorry to you both guys for the delay, I somehow missed that question – it's indeed impossible to gzip the body. In which case would it be useful? What's the usecase? I'll be happy to add this feature if I see some need from users! Thanks in advance :)

Comment: We have a server that wants the contents gzipped.  At the moment my workflow is to create a json text file, gzip it and copy the contents into Paw

Comment: Same situation as Lee here.  I was looking for this feature when I found this question.

Comment: I've not seen it added yet sadly :-(

Comment: @MichaMazaheri our mobile application server accepts only compressed requests. We ended-up using SoapUI - it supports compressed requests and replies

Comment: Oh I never expected this to be as popular :) Will really push this forward for the next version! Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Did this get added at all?  I don't think I saw it?

Comment: This would be a great addition to Paw.

Comment: Yes it would be great, using paw in 2020